# Shifting non static Coordinates in java

Tags: java, point, coordinate

I have a method shift that needs to construct a new object of class `Coordinate` with coordinates shifted `dx` to the right and `dy` down. For example, calling `pos.shift(-1,1)` with `pos` representing the position (1,1) would result in a new position (0,2). Eclipse gives me this error message:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non static method  `shift(int, int)` from type `Coordinate`

This is my piece of code, which should do this shifting:

```
/** move the position by dx to the right and by dy down */
public Coordinate shift(int dx, int dy) {
    pos = pos.shift(this.x + dx, this.y + dy);
}
```

Maybe I am just way too stupid but I have no good idea to solve this.

This is the whole code:

```
 /** represents a position on a board */ 
 public class Coordinate {

  /** variables specifying horizontal position on the board */
  private int x;

  /** variable specifying vertical positoin on the board */
  private int y;

 /** constructor creating a Coordinate from x and y values */
 public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
 }

 /** getter for the x value */
 public int getX() {
     return this.x;
 }

 /** getter for the y value */
 public int getY() {
     return this.y;
 }

 /** check whether this position is valid for the given (quadratic) board size */
 public boolean checkBoundaries(int xSize, int ySize) {
     boolean check;
     if (xSize == (0|1|2) && ySize == (0|1|2)) {
         check = true;
     } else {
         check = false;
     }
 return check;
 }

 /** move the position by dx to the right and by dy down */
 public Coordinate shift(int dx, int dy) {
     pos = pos.shift(this.x + dx, this.y + dy);
 }
}
```

Anyone with a good idea?

Comment: How have you defined the `pos` variable?

Comment: `xSize == (0|1|2)` is not work as you expect.

Comment: Why you're getting that particular error I don't know but there are several problems with the shift method, it refers to a variable pos, which seems not to exist and it does not return anything

Comment: Could we see the entire stack trace?

Comment: By the way are you writing this into a text editor and compiling on the command line or using an IDE (e.g. netbeans) because an IDE would be screaming about these issues the second you wrote them

Comment: @Deepak Thanks for the edit, was mostly good. However be careful to only code format things which are actually code, for example `Coordinate` is code, position (1,1) is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your method `shift` there are several problems

```
 public Coordinate shift(int dx, int dy) {
     pos = pos.shift(this.x + dx, this.y + dy);
 }
```

- This method refers to a variable pos, pos has not been declared and
  so does not exist. It also seems to serve no purpose as all the
  co-ordinate shifting can be done without it.
- Method `shift` has no return statement, meaning that no new `Coordinate` is returned
- If `pos` was a variable of type `Coordinate` then shift would call pos.shift would call pos.shift would call pos.shift etc forever until a StackOverflowException occured

A corrected version of this method is

```
 public Coordinate shift(int dx, int dy) {
     return new Coordinate(this.x + dx, this.y + dy);
 }
```

Note how:

- A new `Coordinate` is created using the constructor
- This new `Coordinate` is passed out of the method

### `Method checkBoundaries(int xSize, int ySize)`

This method does not impact the specific problem mentioned. It doesn't however behave how you think. 0|1 is a [bitwise operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html), it does not give multiple options for a condition. What you wanted was several conditions seperated by the logical operator `||`

```
 public boolean checkBoundaries(int xSize, int ySize) {
     boolean check;
     if ((xSize==0 || xSize ==1 || xSize ==2) && (ySize==0 || ySize ==1 || ySize ==2)) {
         check = true;
     } else {
         check = false;
     }
 return check;
 }
```